# On premises data-gateway needed only one in a on-prem environment or needed in every instance?

Tags: azure, gateway

Hi i was discussing the "on premises data-gateway" with a colleague and we where discussing whether the gateway had to be installed in every instance of a on premises system or it only had to be installed in one throughout the network for the system.

We had some different understanding regarding the documentation specified.

He understood it that installing it on a test server/instance it would be able to reach a database in another "virtual" system in that server.

I had the one understanding that it should be installed in every virtual system where you have a DB you want to reach?

Is there any clarification around this that we have missed?

Hope i made myself somewhat clear on what i'm asking? And please excuse the question if its written in clear text somewhere, we both must have missed it, if so sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

as per document although intended for analysis services, which is practically the same with other services as well,

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway

The on-premise data gateway needs to be installed for each instance of Azure Analysis Services server. In short, if you have two servers that connects to on-premise data sources, you will need two data gateway as well.

In this premise, we both have the same understanding that it needs to be installed for each instance that you need to connect.

Comment: I think that answered my question pretty well, Thank you!
But also Just to be clear, lets give it an example of me having two virtual computers running with sql-databases on each of them, i would have to install the gateway on both, but using the gateway would i have to have different user accounts to log in on the gateway too?

And also how does that work with azure, when i create the On-Premises Data Gateway on my Resource group. I am signed in with one user account. is it only that user account that can manage the data gateway inside for example a logic app? @johnmedina

Comment: You can just have a single account(Azure Account) to Manage your gateways. The credentials needed for the two gateways(if you have two, you need to input two) though needs to be encoded into the Gateway CloudService as they will be decrypted for the on-premise source. source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install#gateway-cloud-service